# How can i deserialize my json in Flutter/dart

Tags: json, flutter, json-deserialization

I'm quite new to flutter and right now i'm stucked in desterilize the json string into my class.
Appreciate your help on this.

This is my json

```
[
 {   
    "itemno": "4800888136473",
    "itemname": "AXE DEO AFRICA 150ML",  
  },
  {  
    "itemno": "4800888141125",
    "itemname": "AXE DEO BODYSPRAY DARK TMPTTN 150ML",   
  }
]
```

And my JSON Class

```
class ListItemList{
  ListItemList({   
    this.itemno,
    this.itemname,   
  });


  String itemno;
  String itemname;
  

  factory ListItemList.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      ListItemList(       
        itemno: json["itemno"],
        itemname: json["itemname"],       
      );
}
```

How i call

```
  List<ListItemList> result =
              ListItemList.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
```

Comment: i always receive the error "list string is not a sub type of list dynamic"

Comment: bro you dont get json, you get list. if you want to construct your object change Map<String,dynamic> to list and use json[index]["itemno"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this link "https://app.quicktype.io/"

And paste your json code left side and add class model name.

for eg.

```
import 'dart:convert';

List<User> userFromJson(String str) => List<User>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => User.fromJson(x)));

String userToJson(List<User> data) => json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

class User {
    User({
        this.itemno,
        this.itemname,
    });

    String itemno;
    String itemname;

    factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => User(
        itemno: json["itemno"] == null ? null : json["itemno"],
        itemname: json["itemname"] == null ? null : json["itemname"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "itemno": itemno == null ? null : itemno,
        "itemname": itemname == null ? null : itemname,
    };
}
```

//Add below code in service

```
static Future<List<User>> getUsers() async {
 List<User> users = usersFromJson(response.body));
 return users;
}
```

// call service in specific page

List _users;

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    ApiService.getUsers().then((value) {
          setState(() {
            _users = value;
          });
        })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `map` to iterate over the JSON which is a list.

```dart
final List<ListItemList> result = (jsonDecode(response.body) as List)
    .map((e) => ListItemList.fromJson(e))
    .toList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to this [URL](https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/) and paste your JSON. It will convert it to both **fromJson** (json to dart object conversion) and **toJson** (dart object to json conversion) function.

Here is as example of fromJson and toJosn according to the Json you provided

```
class List {
  List<Items> items;

  List({this.items});

  List.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    if (json['items'] != null) {
      items = new List<Items>();
      json['items'].forEach((v) {
        items.add(new Items.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    if (this.items != null) {
      data['items'] = this.items.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Items {
  String itemno;
  String itemname;

  Items({this.itemno, this.itemname});

  Items.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    itemno = json['itemno'];
    itemname = json['itemname'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['itemno'] = this.itemno;
    data['itemname'] = this.itemname;
    return data;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As i mentioned it is a list. Deal with list like;

```
 List<ListItemList> result;
     var a = jsonDecode(response.body);
    
    
    // I can not compile this part you can check syntax
    a.forEach((element)
    at= ListItemList.fromJson(element);
    result.add(at);
    );
```